# Which alternative to "Firebase Storage" could I use for my Flutter App?

Tags: flutter, firebase, server, storage

I'm developing an app with Flutter and I need a lot of database storage to store my data (images and videos).

Currently I'm using Firebase for:
"User Authentication, Firestore Database, Dynamic Links, **[Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/start)** and so on"

The **[pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)** for the storage (**GB stored**) itself is ok for me but Firebase also charges for **GB Transfered** and **Operations(uploads & downloads)** which can get expensive as you can see in the snapshot below:

[image: Firebase Pricing Calculator]

I am actually looking for an alternative to Firebase Storage which does not charge for **Data transfer** of **Operations** (at least sth. which is not that expensive).

Does anyone know which cloud storage I could use instead and also how to migrate in my flutter app?

I'm also open to use a own server running on a VPS but I have no clue how I would establish a connection to the own server in order to be able to up- and download media files.

Please provide a tutorial/instructions how to build your own server and connect with flutter app since I'm interested on anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Supabase, it's a Firebase alternative and it's **open source**, supports Flutter/Dart and supports the storage service.

Check it from here [Supabase storage](https://supabase.com/storage)

you could configure it and use it with your own hosting, and it will cost you only the price of hosting it on some cloud service, where you will store your files.

Comment: Which cloud service would you recommend?

Comment: I guess this is up to you and your requirement but I could recommend AWS

Comment: As you can see here https://firebase.google.com/pricing
For 100GB it would be 2.6$ with Firebase Blaze plan.
With Supabase, it is 25$ for 100GB, so it looks much more expensive to me